# не работает редирект .htaccess на телефоне

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

на компьютере все работает и перенаправляет на https версию сайта, но на телефоне открывается http

код файла .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

сайт не на вордпресс

Comment: Обычный кэш. Очистить. Попробуйте в incognito mode.

Comment: кеш очищал, не помогает. в чем может быть проблема?